# Is it possible to use a single DHCP server to push completely different ranges of ip to different network interfaces in different LANs?

Tags: networking, network-interface, dhcp, isc-dhcpd

Is it possible to use a single DHCP server to push completely different ranges of ip to different network interfaces in different LANs?

**EXAMPLE:**

I have the Severs #1 and #2.

**Severs #1:** A DHCP server with a network interface called "enpA" which is connected to LAN A.

**Severs #2:** A DHCP client with an network interface called "enpA" which is also connected to LAN A. It has a network interface called "enpB" which is connected to LAN B.

**LAN A:** 192.168.56.0/24

**LAN B:** 10.0.2.0/24

I wanted the LAN A server (Severs #1) push an ip to the "enpB" (Severs #2) interface which is connected to LAN B. That is, is it possible to do this with a single DHCP server connected in LAN A?

If yes what strategy should I use with a DHCP server like the isc KEA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. What you need to do is run a [DHCP relay agent](https://linux.die.net/man/8/dhcrelay) on server B, which listens for DHCP requests on UDP/67 (UDP/547 for DHCPv6) on its LAN B interface and forwards them to LAN A (the DHCP server obviously needs to be set up to have network pools for both networks!)

The system works something like this:

```
Server 1        LAN A        Server 2         LAN B        Client
                                    *          <--        Request
       *         <--     Request (for Client)
  Answer         -->         *
                        Answer (from Server 1) -->        *
                               [...]
```

DHCPv4 and DHCPv6 relays are handled individually, so you will need two instances of the relay running if you want to handle both types.

Assuming Server A is `192.168.56.1`/`2001:db8:1::1`, and Server B has `eth0`/`192.168.56.2`/`2001:db8:1::2` on LAN A and `eth1`/`10.0.2.1`/`2001:db8:2::1` on LAN B, you would run the relay like this:

- DHCPv4: `/path/to/dhcrelay -4 -i eth1 192.168.56.1`
- DHCPv6: `/path/to/dhcrelay -6 -l eth1 -u eth0`

Note that I haven't had a need to use DHCPv6 relays, so this is based on the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Whilst technically @ErikF's is the right answer to your question as it is asked, it makes much more sense to set up server #2 as a multi-homed DHCP server.

Doing that, you won't need to setup a DHCP relay, and the complexity is also drastically reduced.

Comment: That would be the easiest solution, as server #2 is the only device that can see both networks simultaneously.

Comment: "Whilst technically @ErikF's is the right answer to your question as it is asked" -> Yes, you're right! ErikF did a great job and answered exactly my question, but according to some studies I did it would be better to use an approach like yours and trust in OSI's "Layer 2". ( Thanks "old" friends! =D )

Comment: The only time that I ever actually used a DHCP relay was when I was working on getting my CCNA 20 years ago, so take from that what you will! I would also probably move the DHCP server to the multi-homed server if at all possible.

Comment: @ErikF Yes for sure! Your insight and understanding of both solutions was perfect! Thanks! =D

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's completely possible. I do that on my own setup. There are 2 requirements/conditions:

1. The DHCP server software you're using allows it (there is more than one software for DHCP, perhaps some don't; the "usual" ones do)
2. Both subnets have firewall/routing rules that allow devices in those subnets to successfully query the DHCP server. That might require port mapping, routing rules, one-to-one or outbound NAT (on IPv4) or other methods.

In my case, I use `dhcpd` and the router has 2 network cards, one for each subnet. I set the IP for each subnet to "x.x.x.1". Then my `dhcpd.conf` is as follows.

I've simplified it, and modified it to use your IP addresses, otherwise it's unchanged. If you don't want your router to also be the DNS server/resolver, remove the four lines containing `"option domain-name-servers"`:

```
option domain-name "mydomain.com";
option ldap-server code 95 = text;
option arch code 93 = unsigned integer 16; # RFC4578

default-lease-time 7200;
max-lease-time 86400;
one-lease-per-client true;
deny duplicates;
ping-check true;
update-conflict-detection false;
authoritative;

subnet 192.168.56.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  pool {
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.56.1;
    range 192.168.56.2 192.168.56.254;
  }

  option routers 192.168.56.1;
  option domain-name-servers 192.168.56.1;
}

subnet 10.0.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
  pool {
    option domain-name-servers 10.0.2.1;
    range 10.0.2.2 10.0.2.254;
  }

  option routers 10.0.2.1;
  option domain-name-servers 10.0.2.1;
}
```